Linear subspace of Infinite linear combination, closed or not?
Let $\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in an infinite-dimensional
Lebesgue space $L^{p}(\mathsf{\Omega},\mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$, $1<p<\infty$,
on some probability space $(\mathsf{\Omega},\mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$, and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}=0\iff a_{n}=0\text{ for all }n
$$
Define the subspace
$$
\mathsf{S}=\left\{  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}:a_{n}\in\mathbb{R}
,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
and subsets ($F_{n}$ is defined in the remark)
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Y}  & =\left\{  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert F_{n}\leq1\right\}  \\
\mathsf{T}  & =\left\{  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
a_{n}F_{n}\leq1,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert F_{n}
<\infty\right\}\\
\mathsf{W}  & =\left\{  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}:0\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}a_{n}F_{n}\leq1,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert F_{n}%
<\infty\right\}
\end{align*}
Every $Y\in\mathsf{S}$ can be written in the form $Y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
a_{n}Y_{n}$ (i.e. $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\left\Vert Y-\sum_{n=1}^{m}
a_{n}Y_{n}\right\Vert =0$), thus, $\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Schauder
basis for $\mathsf{S}$ (right?). Note that $\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is
specially selected such that the infinite linear combination $\sum
_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}Y_{n}$ will not escape the $L^{p}$ space.
Remark:

there is a continuous linear function, such that $F_{n}=f(Y_{n})>0$ and
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n}<\infty$. Thinking $Y_{n}$ as a financial asset, then
$F_{n}$ is its price.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert F_{n}<\infty$. Thinking
$a_{n}$ as the number of units of asset $n$ held, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}a_{n}F_{n}$ is the value of the financial portfolio. We make sure it is
absolutely summable, to avoid $\infty-\infty$.

We are using Banach space $L^{p}$, assume that there exists $1<p<\infty$,
such that
$$
\sup\left\{  \operatorname{E}\left(  \left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert
a_{n}Y_{n}\right\vert \right)  ^{p}\right)  :\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert
a_{n}\right\vert F_{n}=1\right\}  <\infty
$$


Question

If $\mathsf{S}=L^{p}$, then $\mathsf{S}$ is closed in $L^{p}$. If
$\mathsf{S}$ is a proper subset of $L^{p}$, such that there exists $X\in
L^{p}$ but $X\notin\mathsf{S}$. Is $\mathsf{S}$ closed in $L^{p}$?

Is $\mathsf{Y}$ closed in $L^{p}$?

Is $\mathsf{T}$ closed in $L^{p}$?

Is $\mathsf{W}$ closed in $L^{p}$? If $\mathsf{W}$ is closed (I badly
want), prove it; otherwise, provide a counterexample.



Looking in $\ell_1$, would defining $Y_n= e_1+ e_{n+1}/n$ give a counterexample?

$\ell_p$ is not defined in a probability space

$L_1$ contains a copy of $\ell_1$.

I add some conditions. Your counterexample escape the space, such that $\operatorname{E}\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n}\right)  =\infty$

Just to clarify, you want $\sum_n a_nY_n \in L^p$ for any possible sequence $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$?

If that is what you want, then this is impossible to satisfy. Just choose $a_n$ inductively so that $|\sum_{n=1}^N a_nY_n| \geq N$ for all $N$, so the infinite sum necessarily diverges.

I update the conditions, to make sure ${Y_n}$ a basis for the subspace

I'm not sure how that's supposed to resolve the issue I raised. Again, as long as you require $\sum_n a_nY_n \in L^p$ for all sequences $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, then this is simply impossible to satisfy. There have to be some constraints on what sequences $a_n$ are admissible.

Perhaps you meant to restrict to sequences $a_n$ with $\sum_n |a_n|F_n < \infty$? In that case, a slight alteration of @DavidMitra 's example applies (change $Y_n$ to $e_1/n^2 + e_{n+1}/n^3$ and let $f$ be the linear functional that picks out the $e_1$ coefficient) and demonstrates that $\mathbf{Y}$ needs not be closed.

I add $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert F_{n}\leq1$

@ChenDeng-Ta Now $\mathbf{Y}$ is no longer a linear subspace, only a subset. Just to make sure, is this what you want? (For example, now it makes no sense to talk about “Schauder basis for $\mathbf{Y}$.”) Also, I’m assuming the $p$ in the question “is $\mathbf{Y}$ closed in $L^p$” the same as the $p$ in requirement 3? If the answers to both questions are yes, then yes, $\mathbf{Y}$ is closed.

thanks very much, I make a slight change, is the T closed? if so, how to prove?

@ChenDeng-Ta In this new version, $\mathbf{S}$ again refers to arbitrary sequences $a_n$. As I have noted before, it is impossible for $\sum_n a_nY_n \in L^p$ for all sequences $a_n$, so your question 1 cannot be answered. For question 2, are you sure you meant $\sum_n a_nF_n \leq 1$ instead of, say, $|\sum_n a_nF_n| \leq 1$? Because in the current form, I can make absolute values of $a_n$ arbitrarily large just by choosing them to be negative.

for the set T, there is another constrain, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert F_{n}<\infty$

@ChenDeng-Ta That constraint doesn’t really prevent $a_n$ from being arbitrarily large in absolute values, neither does this new definition of $\mathbf{W}$, for that matter, but I’ll think about this. The answer is likely no except for $\mathbf{Y}$. But I’ll see if there’s a good counterexample.

I'll start by reiterating my comment that it is impossible for $\sum_n a_nY_n$ to converge for all sequences $a_n$, so question $1$ is impossible to answer in the current form. Now, onto questions $2$ to $4$. The answers to all three questions are no. I'll simply produce an example in which a sequence of elements in $\mathsf{Y} \cap \mathsf{T} \cap \mathsf{W}$ converges to a limit outside all these three sets. This counterexample follows the same general idea as the example mentioned by David Mitra in the comments.
Pick any $1 < p < \infty$. Let $\Omega$ be a countably infinite probability space with the probability measure having full support. By scaling the standard basis (which preserves taking absolute values), we may simply work with $l^p$. (The argument can be easily adapted to any probability space. I'm simply working with $l^p$ for the sake of simplicity.) Now, let $Y_n = \frac{1}{n^2}e_1 + \frac{1}{n^3}e_{n+1}$. Let $f$ be the linear functional on $l^p$ that picks out the $e_1$ coefficient. So, $F_n = f(Y_n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and we indeed have $\sum_n F_n < \infty$. If $\sum_n |a_n|F_n < \infty$, i.e., $\sum_n \frac{|a_n|}{n^2} < \infty$, then $\sum_n \|a_nY_n\| \leq 2 \sum_n \frac{|a_n|}{n^2} < \infty$. So, whenever $\sum_n |a_n|F_n < \infty$, we have $\sum_n a_nY_n$ converges, in fact absolutely. The above also shows that,
$$\sup\{\mathbb{E}((\sum_n |a_nY_n|)^p): \sum_n |a_n|F_n = 1\} \leq \sup\{(\sum_n \|a_nY_n\|)^p: \sum_n \frac{|a_n|}{n^2} = 1\} \leq 2^p$$
So, all conditions listed are satisfied. Now, for any $n_0$, $n_0^2Y_{n_0}$ is in $\mathsf{Y} \cap \mathsf{T} \cap \mathsf{W}$, as it corresponds to the sequence $a_n = 0$ if $n \neq n_0$ and $a_{n_0} = n_0^2$, and,
$$\begin{split}
0 \leq \sum_n a_nF_n = 1 \leq 1\\
\sum_n |a_n|F_n = 1 < \infty
\end{split}$$
But $n_0^2Y_{n_0} = e_1 + \frac{1}{n_0}e_{n_0+1} \to e_1$ as $n_0 \to \infty$. It is, however, easy to observe that $e_1$ cannot even be written as an infinite sum of $Y_n$, which proves the claim.
(I made an error in my thinking when I said in comments that $\mathsf{Y}$ is closed. Because we are working with $p \neq 1$, I messed up and mistakenly didn't notice that the collection of all sequences $a_n$ with $\sum_n |a_n|F_n < \infty$ is an $l^1$ space. In fact, the above example shows that $\mathsf{Y}$ is not necessarily closed.)
